# Symfony Form. Neither the property "TM" nor one of the methods

Tags: symfony2, entity, formbuilder

Возникает ошибка при построении формы.

```
Neither the property "TM" nor one of the methods "getTM()", "isTM()", "hasTM()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Nitra\SchemaCDBBundle\Entity\MonthPlan.
```

Ошибка заключается в том, что `FormBuilder` не находит ни метода не свойства ТМ в классе сущности MonthPlan. Но я не понимаю почему он этот метод ищет именно в сущности MonthPlan.

У меня есть класс `MonthPlan` в нём обозначено отношение к сотрудникам класс `Employee`

```
  /**
 * Сотрудник
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Employee", inversedBy="monthPlans")
 * @Assert\Type(type="Nitra\SchemaCDBBundle\Entity\Employee")
 */
protected $employee;
```

Мне нужно создать форму для класса `MonthPlan` с определёнными сотрдниками из класса `Employee`. Для этих целей я создал класс `Form` и объявил `buildForm`. Как видете в последнем вызове `$builder->add()` Я указал и класс и запрос по которому нужно отбирать сотрудников и свойство по которому отображать результат `'property' =>'name'`, но в конечном итоге я получаю ошибку которую указал выше.

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder->add('chosenType', 'choice', array(
        'required' => true,
        'mapped' => false,
        'choices' => array(
            4 => 'fields.month.eta',
            2 => 'fields.month.TM'
        ),
        'label' => 'fields.month.typeEmployee',
        'translation_domain' => 'Admin'));

    $builder->add('TM', 'entity', array(
        'multiple' => false,
        'em' => 'default',
        'class' => 'NitraSchemaCDBBundle:Employee',
        'required' => false,
        'label' => 'fields.monthPlan.tm',
        'translation_domain' => 'Admin',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->andWhere('u.lvl = :lvl')
                ->setParameter('lvl',2)
                ->addOrderBy('u.sureName','ASC');
        },
        'property' =>'name',
    ));
```

Полный код создания Формы. Есть класс родительски класс `EditType` в который генирируется на основании yml файла. Я его наследую и переопределяю `buildForm`

```
namespace Admingenerated\NitraEmployeeBundle\Form\BaseMonthPlanType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Security\Authorization\Expression\Expression;

class EditType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $securityContext;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('year', array(  'required' => true,  'mapped' => true,  'label' => 'fields.target.choseYear',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('year', new \Nitra\CommonBundle\Form\YearType(), $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('month', array(  'required' => true,  'mapped' => true,  'label' => 'fields.target.choseMonth',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('month', new \Nitra\CommonBundle\Form\MonthType(), $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('target', array(  'multiple' => false,  'em' => 'default',  'class' => 'Nitra\\SchemaCDBBundle\\Entity\\Target',  'required' => false,  'label' => 'fields.monthPlan.target',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('target', 'entity', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('employee', array(  'multiple' => false,  'em' => 'default',  'class' => 'Nitra\\SchemaCDBBundle\\Entity\\Employee',  'required' => true,  'label' => 'fields.monthPlan.employee',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('employee', 'entity', $formOptions);


        $formOptions = $this->getFormOption('summ', array(  'precision' => 12,  'required' => true,  'label' => 'fields.monthPlan.summ',  'translation_domain' => 'Admin',));
        $builder->add('summ', 'number', $formOptions);


    }

    protected function getFormOption($name, array $formOptions)
    {
        return $formOptions;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'edit_monthplan';
    }

    public function setSecurityContext($securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

}
```

Мой пользовательский класс построения формы.

```
namespace Nitra\EmployeeBundle\Form\Type\MonthPlan;

use Admingenerated\NitraEmployeeBundle\Form\BaseMonthPlanType\EditType as BaseEditType;
use Nitra\SchemaCDBBundle\Repository\EmployeeRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Nitra\SchemaCDBBundle\Entity\Employee;
use Nitra\CommonBundle\Form\MonthType;
use Nitra\CommonBundle\Form\YearType;

class EditType extends BaseEditType {

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder->add('chosenType', 'choice', array(
            'required' => true,
            'mapped' => false,
            'choices' => array(
                4 => 'fields.month.eta',
                2 => 'fields.month.TM'
            ),
            'label' => 'fields.month.typeEmployee',
            'translation_domain' => 'Admin'));

        $builder->add('TM', 'entity', array(
            'multiple' => false,
            'em' => 'default',
            'class' => 'NitraSchemaCDBBundle:Employee',
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'fields.monthPlan.tm',
            'translation_domain' => 'Admin',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->andWhere('u.lvl = :lvl')
                    ->setParameter('lvl',2)
                    ->addOrderBy('u.sureName','ASC');
            },
            'property' =>'name',
        ));
    }

    protected function getFormOption($name, array $formOptions) {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'employee':
                $formOptions['query_builder'] = function (EmployeeRepository $er) {
                            return $er->getEmployeeAtPositionEta($this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser());
                        };
                break;
        }
        return $formOptions;
    }

}
```

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста код как вы создаете форму в контроллере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я подозреваю, что в контролере вы подаете энтити при создании формы

```
$monthPlan = new MonthPlan();
$this->createForm(MonthPlanType::class, $monthPlan)
```

В таком случае Symfony автоматически заполнит энтити `$monthPlan` полями формы. Symfony считает что в этой форме все поля формы связаны с полями энтити и в вашем случае он ругается, когда видит поле в форме, но его нету в энтити. Тоесть на фоне после отсылки формы будет происходить `$monthPlan->setTM($value);` что и выдаст ошибку.

Чтобы такое поведение избежать установите полю `'mapped' => false`. Это что-то вроде флага для поля формы, которое говорит, что он не связан с подаваемым энтити и не будет отрабатывать `$monthPlan->setTM($value);`

Можете создть форму без энтити `$this->createForm(MonthPlanType::class, array())` и после отсылки обрабатывать данные так, как вам угодно.

Если такое поведение нужно тогда назовите поле в форме emplyee или создайте поле TM в энтити.

Comment: Вопрос решён, но не могли бы по подробнее объяснить процесс.

Comment: а что именно не понятно?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то если при создании формы я передаю объект класса то форма автоматом строится по свойствам класса. Но в случае если мне нужно создать пользовательское поле мне нужно использовать опцию 'mapped' => false.

Comment: да, именно так. Обновил ответ.