# Sonata admin и поля редактирования двух связанных таблиц

Tags: symfony, symfony3, sonata

Есть две таблицы:

```
/** Category
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Alias")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="aliasId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $alias;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TranslateCategory", mappedBy="category")
 */
private $translate;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->translate    =   new ArrayCollection();
}
```

и

```
/** TranslateCategory
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Locale")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="localeId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $locale;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="translate")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $category;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 */
private $description;
```

Вопрос такой: Как на странице создания/редактирования в sonata admin вывести следующие поля (3 input, 1 textarea) и если это редактирование, то подставлялись данные из бд:

```
Category: name, alias as url; TranslateCategory: title, description
```

Мой мозг додумался только до этого:

```
        $formMapper->add('alias', TextType::class)
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('title', 'sonata_type_model',[
            'class'     =>  'AppBundle\Entity\TranslateCategory',
            'property'  =>  'title',
            'label'     =>  'Title',
        ]);
```

, но не совсем то что надо и ошибки выдает типа:

```
Neither the property "title" nor one of the methods "getTitle()", "title()", "isTitle()", "hasTitle()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Category".
```

т.е. TranslateCategory даже не видит...уже неделю бьюсь, никак понять не могу (и да, документацию изучал, но результата нет...)

Comment: Отредоктировал свой ответ и расширел. Если он вас удолетворил не забудьте поставить отметку.

Comment: Загрузи пожалуйста описания своих сущностей куданибуть на обменик. Что бы я могу у себя развернуть их и написать тебе код и как он работает.

Answer (score 0):

Привет. Ошибку тебе выдаёт потому что у тебя нет метода в сущности `"getTitle()"` Добавь его в сущность TranslateCategory . Ты наверно не сгенерировал геттеры и сеттеры. 
Так же можно воспользоваться свойством `mapped = false`, тогда поля формы нужно будет обрабатывать вручную и вручную инициализировать обьект.

```
 $formMapper->add('alias', TextType::class)
    ->add('name', TextType::class)
    ->add('title', 'sonata_type_model',[
        'class'     =>  'AppBundle\Entity\TranslateCategory',
        'property'  =>  'title',
        'label'     =>  'Title',
        'mapped'    => false,
    ]);
```

Более подробное описание работы опции "mapped" можете посмотреть в моём [Вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648171/symfony-form-neither-the-property-tm-nor-one-of-the-methods)

Answer (score 0):

не так скорее выразился, как мне связать поле `title` с `title` из *entity* `TranslateCategory`?
т.е. вот есть поле `title`, я ввожу туда данные и сохраняю (или открываю для редактирования) и чтобы данное поле показывало связь с `Category` и `TranslateCategory` и записывалось в правильную таблицу.

Допустим, пишу:  `->add('title', 'text'), ['mapped' => false]`

и при сохранении оно должно сохраняться в таблицу `TranslateCategory`.
Может я не правильно *entity* выше сделал или как?
Выше указана связь двух таблиц, я вот и понять не могу как как мне сделать вывод полей для формы:

```
title 'text' из TranslateCategory
name 'text' из Category
alias 'text' из Alias
description 'textarea' из TranslateCategory
```

`mapped` помогает только отобразить, а как и где (и как) мне тогда обрабатывать сохранялку?
P.S.По вашей ссылке понял только как вывести форму, но не как ее потом обрабатывать...

Comment: Похоже Вы хотите задать новый вопрос? Если да, то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Добавьте ссылку на этот вопрос, если есть взаимосвязь.

Comment: вообще-то я хотел прокомментировать предыдущие вопросы (но ауры не хватает, поэтому пишу как новый комментарий). А вопросы те же самые...зачем создавать новый?

Comment: Вы дали ответ. Для комментариев есть кнопки под вопросом и под каждым ответом. Советую посмотреть  "справка", не займёт много времени.

Comment: А, понял, но: _Чтобы оставить комментарий, у вас должно быть 50 баллов репутации_ вот что у меня до этого выпадало, поэтому не мог прокомментировать, извиняюсь (наверно из-за того что до этого как не зарегистрированный юзер комментил), да и сейчас в некоторых местах вылазит...